# Error using Box Least Squares in lightkurve

Tags: python, python-3.x, astropy

I'm using that code

````
```
periods = np.linspace(0.5, 20, 10)
durations = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)

from astropy.stats import BoxLeastSquares
bls = BoxLeastSquares(t=time, y=flux, dy=flux_err)
bls.power(periods, durations)
```
````

But it returns me a error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d582b87a594f> in <module>()
      2 durations = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)
      3 
----> 4 from astropy.stats import BoxLeastSquares
      5 bls = BoxLeastSquares(t=time, y=flux, dy=flux_err)
      6 bls.power(periods, durations)

ImportError: cannot import name 'BoxLeastSquares'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea how correct this, it happened before the new update of lightkurve module 
I'm using the version 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

What version of Astropy are you using?  According to [these docs](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.BoxLeastSquares.html#astropy.stats.BoxLeastSquares)

> This class has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use [`astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquares`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquares.html#astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquares) instead.

This works for me in the latest version:

```
>>> import astropy
>>> astropy.__version__
'3.2.3'
>>> from astropy.timeseries import BoxLeastSquares
```

In general if you get an `ImportError` for a function or class in a library like Astropy that you think should be there, it simply means that it doesn't exist, and so you should carefully check your version by looking at `astropy.__version__`, and compare it to the API documentation for that version to make sure that the thing you're trying to import should actually exist.